# add class based on html in page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form on my page. When the user fills it in and hits submit it then hides the contact form and should display a thank you message.

However i need jquery to rescue me because i dont know enough about PHP to get it working.

I need to check that the form is hidden then create a div with content so the user sees a thank you message. Or add a class of .show to the div so the message appears.

But the main thing is i need to check if the form is hidden.

This is how the html looks when the form is hidden:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="contact.php" method="post" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that hides the contact form?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with the aptly-named [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector.

Assuming the markup of your message element is something like:

```
<div id="thanks_message" style="display: none;">
    Thank you!
</div>
```

You can write:

```
if ($("#contact_form").is(":hidden")) {
    // The form is hidden, show the message.
    $("#thanks_message").show();
}
```

Comment: i have added the div to the page and set it to display:none; then i want to add a class to that div but it wont add because the html element is hidden

Comment: Why would the `<html>` element be hidden? Are you referring to the `<div>` element? Also, since that element is styled with `display: none`, you might want to call `show()` on it instead of adding a class.

Comment: Well i dont want to show the div element by default becase it will say "thank you for the message" on the contact page. I want to hide it then show it with the query.

Comment: That's why you would call `show()` inside the `if` statement, if I understand you correctly. I've tried to elaborate on that in my updated answer.

Comment: I think your code might not work as the style on the form is "display: none"

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean the message is *inside* the form? You will indeed have to put it outside if you want to keep the form hidden.

Comment: Thanks i think i have the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```
if($('#contact_form').is(':visible')) {
    //do stuff if visible
} else {
    //do stuff if hidden
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery to get value of css attributes, like so:

```
var displayVal = $('#contact_form').css('display');
```

And then compare that in an IF-statement. 
Edit: I like the above solution better.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
//to check if form is hidden
if($("#contact_form").css("display") == "none") {
  //show the div here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is how i did it:

http://jsfiddle.net/7QyBV/2/